# Qt4. Why no sizePolicy virtual method in QLayoutItem?

Tags: layout, qt4, qsizepolicy

I want to implement own QLayoutItem successor, but I can't provide QSizePolicy to layout, because no sizePolicy virtual method in QLayoutItem.

I looked into Qt sources and found that QLayout takes sizePolicy directly from QWidget avoiding QWidgetItem.

Why trolls have done so? And what I can do?

Comment: Can you give a bit more detail about what your layout will do? From your comments it almost seems like a QFrame will accomplish your task.

Answer (score 1):

Setting `sizePolicy` using `setSizePolicy ( QSizePolicy )` inside the constructor of your class implementing QLayoutItem doesn't work ?

Comment: QLayoutItem has no setSizePolicy() method and sizePolicy() too :(

Comment: Does that mean you want to change the sizePolicy of the QWidget inside the layout ?

Comment: No. I write own control (QLayoutItem subclass, not a QWidget subclass) and want to put them into QLayout like a spacer. So, I cant provide sizePolicy to QLayout because it's a not QWidget..